# Context sensitive help on compiler messages no longer works in Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10-seattle

I have just installed Delphi Seattle Upgrade 1.

<kbd>f1</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> no longer work when I'm on a compiler warning/error.
I just get `No help found for DCC32`.

This used to work in my previous XE2 version.

Anything I can/should do to fix this?

Note: This is what's shown under the *Details* button:

```
[2086747C]{coreide230.bpl} IDEServices.TToolCompilerMessageLine.ShowHelp (Line 1768, "IDEServices.pas" + 44) + $3
[50067374]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@CheckAutoResult (Line 37599, "System.pas" + 4) + $6
[2086747C]{coreide230.bpl} IDEServices.TToolCompilerMessageLine.ShowHelp (Line 1768, "IDEServices.pas" + 44) + $3
[20794EC9]{coreide230.bpl} MsgViewForm.TMessageViewForm.WMHelp (Line 1298, "MsgViewForm.pas" + 1) + $6
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50997D3D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10079, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 158) + $6
[50AD3514]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4459, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 206) + $5
[5099735C]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9786, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50172214]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16886, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[509A064F]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TDockTree.WindowProc (Line 15441, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $4
[50997E4E]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler (Line 10120, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 30) + $19
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[2198462B]{vclactnband230.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.CallWindowHook (Line 748, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 20) + $F
[50997D3D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10079, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 158) + $6
[21420E8C]{vclide230.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.WndProc (Line 23582, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 32) + $4
[5099735C]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9786, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50172214]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16886, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50997E4E]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler (Line 10120, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 30) + $19
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[183D5D8D]{cxLibraryRS23.bpl} Dxhooks. + $0
[183D5BBD]{cxLibraryRS23.bpl} Dxhooks. + $0
[50997D3D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10079, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 158) + $6
[21420E8C]{vclide230.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.WndProc (Line 23582, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 32) + $4
[5099735C]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9786, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50172214]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16886, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[5098DF2A]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.FindControl (Line 3575, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $9
[50ADCB6F]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10443, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50ADCBB2]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10473, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50ADCEE5]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10611, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) +
```

Note added: all 'regular' help from within the editor works fine; including 3rd party documentation.

Comment: Fwiw, I get the same "No help found..." message in Seattle Update 1, so it's not just you.

Comment: FWIW, what happened with help in XE2 is irrelevant, since current versions use a totally redesigned (reverted to CHM) help system, and therefore are not even the same beast.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a mismatch in the registry keys.
This happens if you install Seattle in one directory, do an uninstall and then reinstall in another directory.

The solution is to fixup the registry entries for the help.

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Help\HtmlHelp1Files`
and manually fix the paths.
I've included a copy/paste from my system.

Note that the `\\` are only in the .reg file. In regedit you'll only see a single `\`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Help\HtmlHelp1Files]
"Dinkumware Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\dinkumware.chm"
"IDE Code Examples Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\codeexamples.chm"
"IDE Data Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\data.chm"
"IDE FireMonkey Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\fmx.chm"
"IDE Libraries Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\libraries.chm"
"IDE System Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\system.chm"
"IDE Topics Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\topics.chm"
"IDE Vcl Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\vcl.chm"
"Indy Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\Indy10.chm"
"TeeChart Help"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\teechart.chm"
"Jcl"="C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\CatalogRepository\\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2.8\\help\\Jcl.chm"
"JclContainers"="C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\CatalogRepository\\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2.8\\help\\JclContainers.chm"
"JclDeveloperTools"="C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\CatalogRepository\\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2.8\\help\\JclDeveloperTools.chm"
"JclVcl"="C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\CatalogRepository\\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2.8\\help\\JclVcl.chm"
"VirtualTreeview"="C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\CatalogRepository\\VirtualTreeView-5.5\\Help\\VirtualTreeview.chm"
"Win32"="C:\\borland\\delphi10\\help\\Doc\\Win32.chm"
```

Once all the paths match the actual locations of the help files, <kbd>F1</kbd> should work again.

Comment: Smart suggestion, but it did not help. I *did* uninstall and reinstall, but all to default paths. All these registry paths point to existing files, with the exception of a missing teechart.chm.